# Calculating Area for data in WGS 84 using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, area

I am using ArcGIS 10.1.1 for Desktop on my laptop.

When I try to calculate the area in WGS 1984 the area is disabled.

If I work in one projection, say WGS 1984, and calculate area in another Projection, is it ok to overcome this problem or it will effect the area calculation?

Can I calculate area using other projection and working in one projection?

Comment: Adding a little additional context, maybe including a screenshot, would be a big help.  Where are you trying to calculate the area? Field calculator or somewhere else?

Comment: I assume, your problem is to know which projection is the best to calculate the area of features. We have geographic coordinate systems, like WGS84, which have explicitly no metric measures. So it's difficult to calculate the area. If you use a geodetic projection, like UTM, than you get metric but more or less distorted measurements for feature areas. But of course you can use calculated areas in different projections.

Comment: means the area remains the same in any of the projection.

Comment: In point of fact, "WGS 84" is not a "projection" -- it's a *geographic* coordinate system (GCS, not PCS).  There are dozens of ways to calculate area, and if you feel like using them all, you could add those dozens of values to the feature class attribute set (with careful naming).  This is less a "problem" than a fundamental fact of geodata..